# How to add new custom field in Magento 1 customer address

Tags: php, magento, onestepcheckout

We have tried this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/add-new-field-in-magento1-9-customer-registration/65760#65760) its all working good for customer edit form,
but now the issue is,

we have used magestore onestepcheckout,

also we have added

```
<li>
                <div class="one-field">
                    <input onkeyup="validateElement(this.id)" type="text"
                               title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Govt ID')) ?>"
                               name="billing[govt_id]" id="billing:govt_id"
                               value="380051"
                               class="input-text"
                               required/>
                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <label class="required" for="billing:govt_id"><?php echo $this->__('Govt ID') ?> <em>*</em></label>
                </div>
            </li>
```

also, we have added,

```
'govt_id' => Mage::helper('onestepcheckout')->__('Govt Id'),
```

in the `position.php` page

but, know while time of billing value of this newly added `govt_id` is not being saved.

Comment: Did you found any solution? @SagarPPanchal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For add new address field, you need to create a new extension.

Here, Step-by-step guide for add `Govt Id` in customer address: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/

Hope it helps you:)